# Enable dual git protocols to work in Visual Studio 2015 and command line

Tags: git, visual-studio, ssh, https

In the cmd line I use git with the ssh protocol for my repo. When I'm in visual studio (2015) it only works over https. I cloned the repo using ssh so I tried adding a new remote:

```
git remote add originHttp https://bitbucket.org/zzz/myrepo.git
```

which is fine - now in the command line I can say:

```
git pull originHttp
```

or

```
 git pull
```

Which uses ssh. It works over either protocol.

In VS2015 it shows both remotes but always uses the ssh one. Is there a way to tell it to use the originHttp remote without removing the ssh one?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have both protocols working.

Working from a repo with all the remotes removed:

```
git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:zzz/myrepo.git
git remote add originHttp https://bitbucket.org/zzz/myrepo.git
git push --set-upstream originHttp master
```

Now it works through VS - the only caveat is I have to be more specific in the cmd line when doing remote operation

```
PS C:>git pull origin master
PS C:>git push origin master
```

**Update**
Another caveat - when pushing I see this message, which makes sense because from git perspective it's a different remote.

```
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'originHttp/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
```

Would love to hear if anyone else has this use case and how you deal with it.